# Meu cadastro de cliente grava "quase" todos os campos

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Estou tendo um problema muito esquisito e acredito que vocês poderão me ajudar.

Tenho um sistema web para controle da empresa, onde possui o cadastro de cliente, os, produtos e etc.

O sistema é em php + codeigniter.

No Controler Clientes, o código é esse:

```
<?php

class Clientes extends CI_Controller {


    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
            if((!$this->session->userdata('session_id')) || (!$this->session->userdata('logado'))){
            redirect('mapos/login');
            }
            $this->load->helper(array('codegen_helper'));
            $this->load->model('clientes_model','',TRUE);
            $this->data['menuClientes'] = 'clientes';
    }   

    function index(){
        $this->gerenciar();
    }

    function gerenciar(){

        if(!$this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'vCliente')){
           $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Você não tem permissão para visualizar clientes.');
           redirect(base_url());
        }
        $this->load->library('table');
        $this->load->library('pagination');


        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/clientes/gerenciar/';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->clientes_model->count('clientes');
        $config['per_page'] = 10;
        $config['next_link'] = 'Próxima';
        $config['prev_link'] = 'Anterior';
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination alternate"><ul>';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li><a style="color: #2D335B"><b>';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</b></a></li>';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['first_link'] = 'Primeira';
        $config['last_link'] = 'Última';
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);     

        $this->data['results'] = $this->clientes_model->get('clientes','idClientes,nomeCliente,documento,docrg,DataNasc,telefone,celular,email,rua,numero,ptoref,bairro,cidade,estado,cep','',$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));

        $this->data['view'] = 'clientes/clientes';
        $this->load->view('tema/topo',$this->data);



    }

    function adicionar() {
        if(!$this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'aCliente')){
           $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Você não tem permissão para adicionar clientes.');
           redirect(base_url());
        }

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->data['custom_error'] = '';

        if ($this->form_validation->run('clientes') == false) {
            $this->data['custom_error'] = (validation_errors() ? '<div class="form_error">' . validation_errors() . '</div>' : false);
        } else {
            $data = array(
                'nomeCliente' => set_value('nomeCliente'),
                'documento' => set_value('documento'),
                'docrg' => set_value('docrg'),
                'DataNasc' => set_value('DataNasc'),
                'telefone' => set_value('telefone'),
                'celular' => set_value('celular'),
                'email' => set_value('email'),
                'rua' => set_value('rua'),
                'numero' => set_value('numero'),
                'ptoref' => set_value('ptoref'),
                'bairro' => set_value('bairro'),
                'cidade' => set_value('cidade'),
                'estado' => set_value('estado'),
                'cep' => set_value('cep'),
                'dataCadastro' => date('d-m-Y')
            );

            if ($this->clientes_model->add('clientes', $data) == TRUE) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Cliente adicionado com sucesso!');
                redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/clientes/adicionar/');
            } else {
                $this->data['custom_error'] = '<div class="form_error"><p>Ocorreu um erro.</p></div>';
            }
        }
        $this->data['view'] = 'clientes/adicionarCliente';
        $this->load->view('tema/topo', $this->data);

    }

    function editar() {
        if(!$this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'eCliente')){
           $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Você não tem permissão para editar clientes.');
           redirect(base_url());
        }
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->data['custom_error'] = '';

        if ($this->form_validation->run('clientes') == false) {
            $this->data['custom_error'] = (validation_errors() ? '<div class="form_error">' . validation_errors() . '</div>' : false);
        } else {
            $data = array(
                'nomeCliente' => $this->input->post('nomeCliente'),
                'documento' => $this->input->post('documento'),
                'docrg' => $this->input->post('docrg'),
                'DataNasc' => $this->input->post('DataNasc'),
                'telefone' => $this->input->post('telefone'),
                'celular' => $this->input->post('celular'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'rua' => $this->input->post('rua'),
                'numero' => $this->input->post('numero'),
                'ptoref' => $this->input->post('ptoref'),                
                'bairro' => $this->input->post('bairro'),
                'cidade' => $this->input->post('cidade'),
                'estado' => $this->input->post('estado'),
                'cep' => $this->input->post('cep')
            );

            if ($this->clientes_model->edit('clientes', $data, 'idClientes', $this->input->post('idClientes')) == TRUE) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Cliente editado com sucesso!');
                redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/clientes/editar/'.$this->input->post('idClientes'));
            } else {
                $this->data['custom_error'] = '<div class="form_error"><p>Ocorreu um erro</p></div>';
            }
        }


        $this->data['result'] = $this->clientes_model->getById($this->uri->segment(3));
        $this->data['view'] = 'clientes/editarCliente';
        $this->load->view('tema/topo', $this->data);

    }

    public function visualizar(){

        if(!$this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'vCliente')){
           $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Você não tem permissão para visualizar clientes.');
           redirect(base_url());
        }

        $this->data['custom_error'] = '';
        $this->data['result'] = $this->clientes_model->getById($this->uri->segment(3));
        $this->data['results'] = $this->clientes_model->getOsByCliente($this->uri->segment(3));
        $this->data['view'] = 'clientes/visualizar';
        $this->load->view('tema/topo', $this->data);


    }

    public function excluir(){

            if(!$this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'dCliente')){
               $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Você não tem permissão para excluir clientes.');
               redirect(base_url());
            }


            $id =  $this->input->post('id');
            if ($id == null){

                $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Erro ao tentar excluir cliente.');            
                redirect(base_url().'index.php/clientes/gerenciar/');
            }

            //$id = 2;
            // excluindo OSs vinculadas ao cliente
            $this->db->where('clientes_id', $id);
            $os = $this->db->get('os')->result();

            if($os != null){

                foreach ($os as $o) {
                    $this->db->where('os_id', $o->idOs);
                    $this->db->delete('servicos_os');

                    $this->db->where('os_id', $o->idOs);
                    $this->db->delete('produtos_os');


                    $this->db->where('idOs', $o->idOs);
                    $this->db->delete('os');
                }
            }

            // excluindo Vendas vinculadas ao cliente
            $this->db->where('clientes_id', $id);
            $vendas = $this->db->get('vendas')->result();

            if($vendas != null){

                foreach ($vendas as $v) {
                    $this->db->where('vendas_id', $v->idVendas);
                    $this->db->delete('itens_de_vendas');


                    $this->db->where('idVendas', $v->idVendas);
                    $this->db->delete('vendas');
                }
            }

            //excluindo receitas vinculadas ao cliente
            $this->db->where('clientes_id', $id);
            $this->db->delete('lancamentos');



            $this->clientes_model->delete('clientes','idClientes',$id); 

            $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Cliente excluido com sucesso!');            
            redirect(base_url().'index.php/clientes/gerenciar/');
    }
}
```

---

No Models Clientes esse é o código:

```
    <?php
class Clientes_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }


    function get($table,$fields,$where='',$perpage=0,$start=0,$one=false,$array='array'){

        $this->db->select($fields);
        $this->db->from($table);
        $this->db->order_by('idClientes','desc');
        $this->db->limit($perpage,$start);
        if($where){
            $this->db->where($where);
        }

        $query = $this->db->get();

        $result =  !$one  ? $query->result() : $query->row();
        return $result;
    }

    function getById($id){
        $this->db->where('idClientes',$id);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        return $this->db->get('clientes')->row();
    }

    function add($table,$data){
        $this->db->insert($table, $data);         
        if ($this->db->affected_rows() == '1')
        {
            return TRUE;
        }

        return FALSE;       
    }

    function edit($table,$data,$fieldID,$ID){
        $this->db->where($fieldID,$ID);
        $this->db->update($table, $data);

        if ($this->db->affected_rows() >= 0)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }

        return FALSE;       
    }

    function delete($table,$fieldID,$ID){
        $this->db->where($fieldID,$ID);
        $this->db->delete($table);
        if ($this->db->affected_rows() == '1')
        {
            return TRUE;
        }

        return FALSE;        
    }

    function count($table) {
        return $this->db->count_all($table);
    }

    public function getOsByCliente($id){
        $this->db->where('clientes_id',$id);
        $this->db->order_by('idOs','desc');
        $this->db->limit(50);
        return $this->db->get('os')->result();
    }

}
```

E no Views AdicionaCliente esse é o código:

```
    <div class="row-fluid" style="margin-top:0">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="widget-box">
            <div class="widget-title">
                <span class="icon">
                    <i class="icon-user"></i>
                </span>
                <h5>Cadastro de Cliente</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-content nopadding">
                <?php if ($custom_error != '') {
                    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . $custom_error . '</div>';
                } ?>
                <form action="<?php echo current_url(); ?>" id="formCliente" method="post" class="form-horizontal" >
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label for="nomeCliente" class="control-label">Nome<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input id="nomeCliente" type="text" name="nomeCliente" value="<?php echo set_value('nomeCliente'); ?>"  />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label for="documento" class="control-label">CPF/CNPJ<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input id="documento" type="text" name="documento" value="<?php echo set_value('documento'); ?>"  />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label for="docrg" class="control-label">R.G.<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input id="docrg" type="text" name="docrg" value="<?php echo set_value('docrg'); ?>"  />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label for="DataNasc" class="control-label">Data de Nascimento<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input id="DataNasc" type="text" name="DataNasc" value="<?php echo set_value('DataNasc'); ?>"  />
                        </div>
                    </div>                    
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label for="telefone" class="control-label">Telefone<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input id="telefone" type="text" name="telefone" value="<?php echo set_value('telefone'); ?>"  />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label for="celular" class="control-label">Telefone 2<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input id="celular" type="text" name="celular" value="<?php echo set_value('celular'); ?>"  />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label for="email" class="control-label">Email<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input id="email" type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>"  />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group" class="control-label">
                        <label for="rua" class="control-label">Rua<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input id="rua" type="text" name="rua" value="<?php echo set_value('rua'); ?>"  />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label for="numero" class="control-label">Número<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input id="numero" type="text" name="numero" value="<?php echo set_value('numero'); ?>"  />
                        </div>
                    </div>

            <div class="control-group" class="control-label">
                        <label for="ptoref" class="control-label">Ponto de Referência<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input id="ptoref" type="text" name="ptoref" value="<?php echo set_value('ptoref'); ?>"  />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group" class="control-label">
                        <label for="bairro" class="control-label">Bairro<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input id="bairro" type="text" name="bairro" value="<?php echo set_value('bairro'); ?>"  />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group" class="control-label">
                        <label for="cidade" class="control-label">Cidade<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input id="cidade" type="text" name="cidade" value="<?php echo set_value('cidade'); ?>"  />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group" class="control-label">
                        <label for="estado" class="control-label">Estado<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input id="estado" type="text" name="estado" value="<?php echo set_value('estado'); ?>"  />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group" class="control-label">
                        <label for="cep" class="control-label">CEP<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input id="cep" type="text" name="cep" value="<?php echo set_value('cep'); ?>"  />
                        </div>
                    </div>



                    <div class="form-actions">
                        <div class="span12">
                            <div class="span6 offset3">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Adicionar</button>
                                <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/clientes" id="" class="btn"><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i> Voltar</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="<?php echo base_url()?>js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#formCliente').validate({
            rules :{
                  nomeCliente:{ required: true},
                  documento:{ required: true},
                  docrg:{ required: true},
                  DataNasc:{ required: true},
                  telefone:{ required: true},
                  email:{ required: true},
                  rua:{ required: true},
                  numero:{ required: true},
                  bairro:{ required: true},
                  cidade:{ required: true},
                  estado:{ required: true},
                  cep:{ required: true}
            },
            messages:{
                  nomeCliente :{ required: 'Campo Requerido.'},
                  documento :{ required: 'Campo Requerido.'},
                  docrg :{ required: 'Campo Requerido.'},
                  DataNasc :{ required: 'Campo Requerido.'},
                  telefone:{ required: 'Campo Requerido.'},
                  email:{ required: 'Campo Requerido.'},
                  rua:{ required: 'Campo Requerido.'},
                  numero:{ required: 'Campo Requerido.'},
                  bairro:{ required: 'Campo Requerido.'},
                  cidade:{ required: 'Campo Requerido.'},
                  estado:{ required: 'Campo Requerido.'},
                  cep:{ required: 'Campo Requerido.'}

            },

            errorClass: "help-inline",
            errorElement: "span",
            highlight:function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('error');
            },
            unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                $(element).parents('.control-group').removeClass('error');
                $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('success');
            }
           });
      });
</script>
```

---

De tudo isso, a única coisa que acontece é que não está gravando no banco os registros RG, Telefone 2 (celular) e Ponto de Referência (ptoref).

E já no arquivo EditaCliente (no views), qdo reinsiro os dados que faltam, grava tudo perfeitamente. Logicamente que não quero ficar a vida inteira adicionando cliente e editando novamente o mesmo, basta adicionar e pronto.

O que pode estar errado, pois eu não achei erro nenhum.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

esse é a tabela de clientes. E pelo visto está tudo igual.

Comment: Registro é uma linha da tabela, RG, telfone2 e outros são campos.

Comment: Os nomes em `$data` não estão diferentes na tabela clientes?

Comment: Desde já agradeço pela agilidade... Vou verificar depois eu posto aqui.

Comment: Outra coisa o editar está diferente do inserir, no primeiro está  `$this->input->post('nome')` e no segundo apenas `set_value('nome')` desconfio que seja isso, pelo menos nunca vi recuperar os valores da request assim.

Comment: Pois é... eu tentei alterar o AdicionaCliente.php com os dados do EditaCliente.php (que está perfeito), más dá um erro esquisito... vou fazer aqui e depois posto o print...

Comment: F U N C I O N O O O O O U ........ comentei o código anterior (aquele do set_value) e apenas copiei o código utilizado na function editar... e funcioou PERFEITAMENTE...

Comment: Muito Obrigado rray.

Comment: Você mudou os `set_value()` por `$this->input->post()` e funcinou?

Comment: isso mesmo... mudei e deu certo. Agradeço por sua ajuda!

Comment: @JardelDint, marque a resposta do rray como aceita. :)

Answer (score 0):

Na hora de montar o array para gravar(`adicionar()`) os dados não use o helper `set_value()`, os valores vem o form e para recupera-los usa-se `$this->input->post()` existe uma versão para o `get` também.

Mude:

```
$data = array(
        'nomeCliente' => set_value('nomeCliente'),
        'documento' => set_value('documento')
        ... demais
```

Para:

```
$data = array(
        'nomeCliente' => $this->input->post('nomeCliente'),
        'documento' => $this->input->post('documento')
        ... demais
```